# In an Atom package, how do I style patterns in a grammar?

Tags: css, package, atom-editor, custom-formatting

I want to create a very simple custom [atom](https://atom.io/) package where I highlight specific words based on regular expressions. I am working with configuration files dealing with lots of ip addresses. I want to color ip address 1.1.1.1 red for example, 0.0.0.0 blue etc...

**It is so simple to create a package this is what I have done:**

Created file:
`C:\Users\MyUsername\.atom\packages\MyPackage\package.json`

```
{
  "name": "language-conf",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Syntax highlighting for configuration files",
  "engines": {
    "atom": "*"    
  }
}
```

AND file:
`C:\Users\MyUsername\.atom\packages\MyPackage\grammars\rules.cson`

```
'scopeName': 'source.conf'  
'name': 'CONF'  
'fileTypes': ['CONF']  
'patterns': [  
  {
    'match': '1\.1\.1\.1'
    'name': 'constant.numeric.integer.hexadecimal.python'
  },
  {
    'match': '0\.0\.0\.0'
    'name': 'constant.numeric.integer.hexadecimal.python'
  }
]
```

When I open a configuration file this is how it looks:

[image]

**Note how ips are formated and that is great!** How can I pick colors for different ips though? All the ips are colored yellow. It will be nice if instead of the name property there was a color property.

---

### Edit

In summary I will like to style this example:

http://blog.gaku.net/create-a-custom-syntax-highlighting-with-atom-editor/

In that link it does not show you how to place different color/styles to different rules.

Answer (score 9):

To style different patterns with different colors in Atom, first assign a different name to each pattern in your `rules.cson`:

```
'scopeName': 'source.conf'  
'name': 'CONF'  
'fileTypes': ['CONF']  
'patterns': [  
  {
    # note that you should be using '\\' instead of '\' to escape '.'
    'match': '1\\.1\\.1\\.1'
    'name': 'style1'
  },
  {
    'match': '0\\.0\\.0\\.0'
    'name': 'style0'
  }
]
```

Next create a `C:\Users\MyUsername\.atom\packages\MyPackage\styles\styles.less` file that defines CSS styles with the desired colors for each pattern name:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
    .style0 {
      color: blue;
    }
    .style1 {
      color: red;
    }
}
```

Then reload the Atom window (`Ctrl+Alt+R`), and you should see your patterns with the assigned colors:

[image: Atom showing colored IP addresses]

This works because:

- Style sheets are [automatically pulled](http://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/package-word-count/#packagejson) from the `styles` directory when not explicitly defined in `package.json`
- Styles that are combined with the [`atom-text-editor::shadow`](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#styling-the-editor) pseudo-element are applied to the editor

Comment: In my case the default shortcut to reload atom and therefore see the changes was: [ctrl]+[shift]+[F5]

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question a long time ago. My solution stopped working, so I came back to it. For some reason, now I have to append the 'syntax' keyword to my style. In other words my `\styles\styles.less` file now looks like:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
    .syntax--style0 {
      color: red;
    }
    .syntax--style1 {
      color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a link that point to the explanation of some changes in how to write a style (and why tha added "syntax" prefix):
https://flight-manual.atom.io/shadow-dom/sections/removing-shadow-dom-styles/

I hope it would help as it helped me. I was getting mad on why my style was not functioning.